# extracting tensor values given tensor index values torch

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, slice

I have a tensor of values `val` with shape `(b,n)` and a tensor of indexes `ind` with shape `(b,m)` (where `n>m`). My goal is to take the values in `val` that corresponds to the indexes in `ind`. Ive tried using `val[ind]`, but it only expanded the dimensions of `val`, rather than taking only the relevant items

```
val = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],
                    [4,5,6],
                    [7,8,9],
                    [10,11,12],
                    [13,14,15]])   
ind = torch.tensor([[1,2],
                    [0,2],
                    [0,1],
                    [1,2],
                    [0,1]])
val[ind] # shaped (5,2,4), I need (5,2)
```

the wanted output is

```
torch.tensor([[2,3],
              [4,6],
              [7,8],
              [11,12],
              [13,14]])
```

Comment: What do your indices represent? I mean, for example, does `[1, 2]` represent row 1 and column 2 in `val`? If so, how do you expect a matrix of shape `(5, 2)` since you will get 5 values with such representation of indices?

Comment: I've edited the example to be more self-explanatory. basically, every row in `ind` represents the row indexes I need to extract from `val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform such operation using [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html):

```
>>> val.gather(dim=1, index=ind)
tensor([[ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  6],
        [ 7,  8],
        [11, 12],
        [13, 14]])
```

Essentially indexing `val`'s 2nd dimension using `ind`'s values. The returned tensor `out` follows:

```
out[i][j] = val[i][ind[i]]
```